# Why is my class node overwriting itself instead of making a new node object

Tags: c++, list, templates, overwrite

can someone run this code and tell me why the node in insert keeps overwriting?

```
#ifndef LinkedList_hpp
#define LinkedList_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <utility>

template<class T>class LinkedList{
public:
LinkedList(){
        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;
        size = 0;
    }
    //void insert(T val);
    class Node{
        public:
        Node* next;
        T* value;
        Node* prev;
        Node(T* value){
            this->value = value;
        }
        Node(){
        }
        Node(T* value,Node* prev, Node* next){
            this->value = value;
            this->next = next;
            this->prev = prev;
        }
        Node* operator=(const Node& node){
            this->value = node.value;
            this->prev = node.prev;
            this->next = node.next;
            return *this;
        }

    };
public:
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    int size;
    void insert(T val){
```

at this line, if the previous head was 10, the current val, 40, overwrites the old head value and inserts a new node with val 40

```
        Node* temp = new Node(&val);
        if(head==nullptr){
            head = temp;
            tail = temp;
        }else{
            temp->next = head;
            head->prev = temp;
            head = temp;
        }
        size++;
    }
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include "LinkedList.hpp"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

   // LinkedList<int> t;
    int h = 7;
    int j = 10;
    int k = 40;
    LinkedList<int>* list1 = new LinkedList<int>();


    list1->insert(h);
    list1->insert(j);
    list1->insert(k);

return 0;
}
```

every time insert is called and a new node is constructed, it overwrites the old value and everything becomes the current Val

Answer (score 2):

```
void insert(T val){
```

`val` is a parameter to this function. This object, this `val`, only exists until this function returns. At which point it gets destroyed, like everything else declared in non-static scope inside the function. That's how C++ works. Once `insert()` returns, this `val` no more. It ceases to exist. It goes to meet its maker. It becomes an ex-object, that no longer exist and is completely in the past.

Your `insert()` function does the following:

```
Node* temp = new Node(&val);
```

You're passing a pointer to this `val` parameter to `Node`'s constructor, and `Node` then saves the pointer to a parameter to `insert()`, as its own class member.

That's great, but as soon as `insert()` returns, the saved pointer in the `new`-ed `Node` becomes a pointer to a destroyed object, and dereferencing this pointer becomes undefined behavior.

You are then, later, attempting to dereference the original pointer, which is no longer pointing to a valid object.

This explains the observed undefined behavior in your code.

The bottom line is that your classes and templates's design is fundamentally flawed. There is no apparent purpose for `Node` to use a pointer. `Node` should simply store `T` as its own class member, as the `value`, instead of `value` being a pointer to some other `T` which exists somewhere, and can get destroyed at any time, which is not under `Node`'s control.

Another problem in the shown code is that  two of`Node`'s constructor fail to initialize the `next` and `prev` pointers to `NULL`. This will also lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: THANKS! I fixed the issue by not making val a pointer. The way you explained it made a lot of sense. I was under the impression that the object pointed to maintained scope but I guess not. TY!

Answer (score 1):

```
void insert(T val)
```

takes its arguments by value, so `val` is a local copy rather than the original.

```
Node* temp = new Node(&val);
```

stores a pointer to this local copy. The copy goes out of scope, so what you're looking at after insert exits is a ghost existing in memory that is no longer valid. In this case the ghost appears to always hold the last value set.

## Solution:

Smart way: Store `Node::value` directly instead of as a pointer that you need to keep alive along with the node. Much less memory management this way.

```
T* value;
```

becomes

```
T value;
```

and

```
Node(T* value){
    this->value = value;
}
```

becomes

```
Node(T value){
        this->value = value;
}
```

The other uses of `value` must be updated accordingly. In general, `new` is such a headache that [it should be used sparingly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new).

Stupid way: Pass by reference

```
void insert(T &val)
```

so that the pointer points at the longer lived original.